# How to use properly the shared BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, tree, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a binary tree in which every node represents a electronics gate (AND, OR, ...). My mission is to calculate the total value of the tree (like this one in the picture, a binary tree):

[image: tree]

This is my code so far (without the threads implementation):

gate_node:

```
public class gate_node {
    gate_node right_c, left_c;
    Oprtator op;
    int value;
    int right_v, left_v;

    public gate_node(gate_node right, gate_node left, Oprtator op) {
        this.left_c = left;
        this.right_c = right;
        this.op = op;
        right_v = left_v = 0;
    }

    void add_input(int right_v, int left_v){
        this.right_v=right_v;
        this.left_v=left_v;
    }

    int compute(int array_index, int arr_size) {
        /*
         * The following use of a static sInputCounter assumes that the
         * static/global input array is ordered from left to right, irrespective
         * of "depth".
         */

        final int left, right;
         System.out.print(this.op+"("); 

        if (null != this.left_c) {
            left = this.left_c.compute(array_index,arr_size/2);
            System.out.print(",");
        } else {
            left = main_class.arr[array_index];
            System.out.print(left + ",");
        }

        if (null != this.right_c) {
            right = this.right_c.compute(array_index + arr_size/2,arr_size/2);
            System.out.print(")");
        } else {
            right = main_class.arr[array_index + 1];

            System.out.print(right + ")");
        }

        return op.calc(left, right);
    }
}
```

Oprtator:

```
public abstract class Oprtator {
    abstract int calc(int x, int y);
}
```

And

```
public class and extends Oprtator {
    public int calc(int x, int y){
        return (x&y);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class or extends Oprtator {
    public int calc(int x, int y){
        return (x|y);
    }
}
```

The tree:

```
public class tree implements Runnable {
    gate_node head;

    tree(gate_node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    void go_right() {
        head = head.right_c;
    }

    void go_left() {
        head = head.left_c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

main class

```
public class main_class {
    public static int arr[] = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tree t = new tree(new gate_node(null, null, new and()));

        t.head.right_c = new gate_node(null, null, new or());

        t.head.right_c.right_c = new gate_node(null, null, new and());
        t.head.right_c.left_c = new gate_node(null, null, new and());

        t.head.left_c = new gate_node(null, null, new or());

        t.head.left_c.right_c = new gate_node(null, null, new and());
        t.head.left_c.left_c = new gate_node(null, null, new and());

        int res = t.head.compute(0, arr.length);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The result is: " + res);
    }
}
```

I want to calculate it using thread pool, like this algorithm:

**Preparation:**

1. Implement each gate as a class/object. It has to have 2 attributes: input A, input B and a way to calculate result;
2. Implement a tree. Each node is a pair (gate, next_node). Root is a node with next_node being null. Leaves are nodes such that no other node points to it.
3. Use a shared (thread safe) queue of nodes. It is initially empty.
4. There is a fixed number (pick one, does not depend on number of gates) of threads which continuously wait for an element from the queue (unless the result is reached in which case they just quit).

**Loop:**

1. Whenever an input occurs on a node put the node in a queue (at the beginning inputs go to leaves). This can be simply implemented by defining add_input method on a gate.
2. A thread picks up a node from queue:
3. 1. If one of the input is missing discard it (it will be there one more time when second input appears). Another idea is to put the node in a queue only when both inputs are there.
   2. If both inputs are there, then calculate result and pass it to next_node if it is not null (and put next_node in the queue). If next_node is null, then this is your result - break the loop and finalize.

the only problem is that I don't know how to create a shared BlockingQueue that every node object in the tree can insert himself into it, and how to create an array of  fixed sized of threads that constantly waits for new elements in the queue to be available (and then execute them)..... until the head is removed from the list (meaning we are done calculating).

I searched online for BlockingQueue examples but I only found producer and consumer examples and I'm having a hard time to move those example to fit my problem. I would really appreciate it if anyone could try to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a few starting pointers to get you going :)

To create your threads just spawn that many threads:

```
for (int i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++) {
    new Thread(myRunnable).start();
}
```

You may well want to store a reference to those threads but it isn't required. The threads need no special setup as they are all identical and they all just sit there grabbing items off the queue.

To share a blocking queue the simplest way is just to make it static and final:

```
static final BlockingQueue blockingQueue();
```

Now all the threads can access it.

Incidentally if I was doing this I wouldn't use the Queue at all, I'd use a ThreadPoolExecutor and just send the processing to that as new runnables.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html